# Why is my React demo App parent tree setting of height:100% acting as 100vh instead?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am creating a web app and I want the behavior that when the user presses the hamburger button, the `side drawer` pushes the entire content to the right.

on the link below you will see a dummy `Main` component, that simulates any content placed within the header and the footer.

At the `Layout` `Component's` `grid` I meant to have the `main` section with a `row` `height` of `auto` to take advantage of all the available space left after setting the `header` and the `footer`. To ensure that this would work I have added `height: 100%` to all the parent `tags` wright up to the `root` `html`.

If I set the height of anything inside `Main` that surpasses the total height left of the `viewport` (check on mobile view on your `browser dev tools`) the page breaks, having the content overflowing the total `height`. You will notice that the `Backdrop` and the `SideDrawer` will not cover the whole page anymore, leaving a part out of it.

I want a behavior that when the `main` content gets bigger than what is left from the `100%` height everything gets pushed down and the browser reads `100%` `height` including the content.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

I will just add my `sidedrawer` and `Layout` stuff here, as you can test this little demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/parent-tree-to-100-xv91m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Layout.scss";
import Toolbar from "../../Components/Toolbar/Toolbar";
import Footer from "../../Components/Footer/Footer";
import SideDrawer from "../../Components/Sidebar/SideDrawer";

const Layout = props => {
  const [toggler, setToggler] = useState(false);
  const buttonTogglerHandler = () => {
    setToggler(!toggler);
  };
  const cssClasses = [
    "Layout",
    toggler ? "Layout__slideOn" : "Layout__slideOff"
  ];
  return (
    <div className={cssClasses.join(" ")}>
      <Toolbar toggler={toggler} onToggled={buttonTogglerHandler} />
      <SideDrawer show={toggler} close={buttonTogglerHandler} />
      <main>{props.children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

```
.Layout {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid: {
    template-rows: 3rem auto 5rem;
    template-areas: "header" 
                    "main" 
                   "footer"
  }

&__slideOn {
animation: slideLayout 300ms forwards ease-in;
@keyframes slideLayout {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(80%);
  }
}
}

&__slideOff {
  animation: unslideLayout 300ms forwards ease-out;
  @keyframes unslideLayout {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(80%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  }
}
  & main {
    grid-area: main;
  }

  & footer {
    grid-area: footer;
  }
}
```

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./Sidebar.scss";
import Backdrop from "../../UI/Backdrop/Backdrop";
import CSSTransition from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition';

const SideDrawer = props => {
  return (
    <CSSTransition
      in={props.show}
      mountOnEnter
      unmountOnExit
      timeout={300}
      classNames={{
        enterActive: "Sidebar__open",
        exitActive: "Sidebar__close"
      }}
    >
      <Fragment>
        <div className="Sidebar">sidebar</div>
        <Backdrop show={props.show} closeBackdrop={props.close} />
      </Fragment>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

```
.Sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -80vw;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .5;

  &__open {
    animation: openSidebar 300ms forwards ease-in;
    @keyframes openSidebar {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0)
      }
      
      100% {
        transform: translateX(80%)
      }
    }
  }

  &__close {
    animation: closeSidebar 300ms forwards ease-out;
    @keyframes closeSidebar {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0)
      }
      
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My parent tree should be set to 100% up to the point where I have the `div` holding the `.Layout` `class`. On this element one must add the `min-height` feature, to expand over the `100%` of the screen set `upstream` the `component tree`.

This means that the `component tree`, from the `html` to one level above the `Layout` `Component`, the latter which holds a middle `grid row` with a `auto height` setting, will then be able to expand this `row` over the `100% height` when needed:

- In case the total `height` of the `app` screen is higher than the `viewport`
- Will also ensure that the `app` covers al least `100%` of the viewport in case the total height of the `app` is smaller than the `viewport`.

By then providing the coverage of the entire app, from the `header` down to the `footer`.

Here is the correct behavior @ [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/parent-tree-to-100-xv91m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)